# How to have a picture box follow cursor c# windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am making a shooting game where you click on the targets to score a point, i was wondering how I could have it so i have a picture box instead of the cursor, to act as an aiming reticle.

Comment: You need to get a book or find a tutorial; Windows Forms are too complicated to learn by guessing. For example, to draw anywhere inside a form you need to create a `Canvas` control and draw into that in your `Paint` event handler. Do not try to use a `PictureBox` control for interactive drawing.

Comment: You could simply use the Crosshair cursor or create a (b&w) custom cursor.. Using a PictureBox is also possible but since you will want it to have transparency you must make sure that it is __nested__ in the form (or whatever container) and will __never overlap__ anything, esp. not controls you use as targets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can achieve this need by subscribing to the event `MouseMove` of the form. Then get the mouse position through the code and reset the position of PictureBox.

Here is a demo you can refer to.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShowCursor", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public extern static void ShowCursor(int status);

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p1 = MousePosition;
    // Get the mouse position in the form
    Point p2 = PointToClient(p1);
    // Reset picturebox location
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(p2.X - pictureBox1.Width /2 , p2.Y - pictureBox1.Height /2);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load picture
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\pic123\target.png");
    // Hide cursor
    ShowCursor(0);
}
```